# How to take the entire command line text as an argument to a bash function?

Tags: bash

I'd like to be able to do this

```
be rake db:migrate
```

instead of this

```
be "rake db:migrate"
```

How to write this function?

```
function be() {   
  bundle exec ??? 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this using an `alias`

```
// .bash_profile
alias be="bundle exec"
```

I'd even consider just making it

```
alias be="bundle exec rake"
```

As I never really need it for anything other than `rake` tasks and I always forget to write rake. If it's a special case then I don't mind typing `bundle exec` in full.

As @holygeek points out an `alias` is the right tool for the job here.

Answer (score 4):

`"$@"` is what you are looking for.

Explanation for $@ from bash manual:

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion  occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ....

Comment: You'd use it like this: `bundle exec "$@"`

Comment: Wish I could select two correct answers.  This answers the function question, though Paul.s and holygeek's gave the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the expression with backticks will execute the output of the enclosed function.

```
`rake db:migrate`
```

Comment: this is a backtick: `\`` -- this is a tilde: `~`

Comment: Thanks. I also realized this is not the answer Gavin is looking for, so my post is worthless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use function for this. Alias is what you want (it's the right tool here):

```
alias be='bundle exec'
```